ERROR TOMCAT AL INICIAR APLICACION
Error 404 al desplegar aplicación en Tomcat: Tomcat retorna http status error: 404
Buen día, tengo una consulta sobre un problema que estoy enfrentando al ejecutar mi aplicación Java EE en Tomcat.
Al intentar desplegar mi aplicación utilizando el plugin Maven tomcat7-maven-plugin, obtengo el siguiente error en la consola:
[ERROR] Tomcat return http status error: 404, Reason Phrase: : {"timestamp":"2024-10-06T19:00:29.842+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/manager/text/deploy"}

Además, al iniciar Tomcat, recibo este error:
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector["http-nio-8080"]]

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
Tomcat Version: 10.1.30
Java Version: JDK 21
Plugin Maven: tomcat7-maven-plugin 2.2
¿Alguien podría ayudarme a entender por qué recibo el error 404 y cómo solucionarlo? ¿Podría ser un problema de configuración en Tomcat o en el plugin de Maven?
Lo extraño es que ayer funcionaba perfecto
Agradezco cualquier orientación que puedan proporcionar.
Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

El error 404 indica que el recurso que intentas acceder no existe, pero también tienes este mensaje:

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Que indica que el puerto que tratas de usar ya esta siendo usado, puedes cambiar el puerto a otro disponible, de forma predeterminada se tiene definido el port="8080", esto se realiza editando el archivo /server.xml de Tomcat
cambia a otro puerto disponible:
<Connector port="8081" 


si, era eso muchas gracias !

@tizianafrisch recuerda que si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, puedes marcarla como solución, revisa [tour], saludos.
